# How to correctly install deluged on Debian (raspberry)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, deluge

I am trying to install deluged on my raspberry pi, but it seems that none of the many tutorials I followed are valid with my installation.

What I did first is:

```
sudo apt-get install deluged
```

From this tutorials say that the config is (depending on the tutorial):

```
~/.deluge/
/var/lib/deluge/
/var/lib/deluged/
/opt/deluge/config/
/etc/default/deluged/
...
```

Many other tutorials recommend to create a `deluge` user, but it seems `apt-get` already created the `debian-deluge` user.

What is the single source of truth associated to my `apt-get install deluged` installation? How do I know:

- What was installed?
- What users were created?
- Where are the config files?
- ...

Of course this question is related to deluge, but I think the answer could be generic to any program installed through `apt-get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to have a list of the files installed by a package just type (no need to be root):

```
dpkg -L <package>
```

To view the list of config files for the package:

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.conffiles
```

In that directory you will also find two more interesting files: `<package>.preinst` and `<package>.postinst`, which are shell scripts executed by the package manager before and after the installation of the package. Examining those script will give you all the details you need about the changes performed to your system upon package installation/upgrade/removal.